# AWS SDK V3 S3Client in web worker throws ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: vue.js, web-worker, aws-sdk-js

In a Vue JS app I am using a web worker to generate signed URLs.  This code worked with no problem using `@aws-sdk/client-s3` version 3.0.0.  However, later versions fail the `getSignedUrl()` call with the error "`ReferenceError: window is not defined`".

```js
(worker.js)

import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

async function generateUrls(s3config, bucket, filename) {

  let getParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: filename
  };
  let url;

  const clientS3 = new S3Client(s3config);

  const getCmd = new GetObjectCommand(getParams);
  try {
    url = await getSignedUrl(clientS3, getCmd);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error getting signed URL ', err);
  }

  return url;
}
```

I know web workers run in a different context and don't have access to the main thread's *window*. I have traced into the AWS library client-s3 after 3.0.0 and seen that (for some reason) it assumes the existence of *window*.

Is there some trick to using the S3 client in a web worker or is this a bug?

Comment: Note that this problem was fixed in @aws-sdk/client-s3 version 3.12.0, so this has become a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked for me on AWS dynamodb by putting this somewhere on the code

```
if(typeof window != "object")
    self.window = self;
```

v3 is working now on cloudflare.

Comment: You are the man @JohnnyRivers, that absolutely solved the problem!  For the sake of others finding this, we should clarify that when you say "somewhere in the code" you mean "somewhere within the web worker module" since the assignment has to be in the web worker's context, which is separate from the main thread.  FWIW I had flailed unsuccessfully with attempts to declare `window` externally in the module and did not understand that `self.window` satisfies attempts to access `window` in library calls.